# Padding/Margin Percentages - Possible CSS bug?

Tags: css

So I'm busy making a horizontally scrolling site. The container `div` we'll say has a class of `area`. It's width is variable, in the same way an average `div`'s height would be variable on a conventional site.

My site is "vertically responsive" so I'm using a lot of percentage values, including heights, in the same way you would use percentage widths on a usual site.

The problem is that when I use percentage padding/margin on my `div.area` it calculates the percentage based on the width of the div as opposed to the height, even when setting `padding-top` for example.

This is akin to trying to set a percentage `padding-left` on the `body` of a normal site and having the padding calculated based on the height of the site. It's bonkers and completly unintuitive.

Is this a known issue? Or is it intentional? And are there any CSS-only work-arounds. I don't want to have to use JS or something to solve something like this I'd rather just set padding in `em`s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The W3C standards dictate that any percentages for [paddings](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties) and [margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties) are a percentage of the element's width, not height:

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the
>   generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for
>   'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well. If the containing block's
>   width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined
>   in CSS 2.1.

However, the `top` and `bottom` positions are determined by the container height, though ;) There is no single CSS-only way to do it, but if you are willing to throw in some JS, that's entirely possible.

Some solutions that I can think of (non-exhaustive list):

1. Displacement from top by 50% (CSS only), and then offset by negative top margin that is half of the element's own height (JS-based calculation)
2. Calculate top and bottom paddings/margins by JS after determining container height

Answer (score 0):

just stumbled upon the same problem. solution that works for me:

dont set width/height and use

```
.percent10 {
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  right: 10%;
}
```